# How to use reserved words without backquotes in MySQL

Tags: mysql, keyword, quotes, cross-database, reserved

I would like to use reserved words such as "user" or "right" as table or column names in my databases. Until now I've been using back quotes, but I read somewhere that they are MySQL specific, and I would like to preserve database compatibility. I've also read about using ANSI mode with MySQL to avoid using back quotes, but I want everything in my apps to be UTF-8.

What can I do to use reserved words without using back quotes or losing cross database compatibility ?

Comment: In ANSI SQL the double-quote serves this purpose. Does it work on MySQL? I do not know.

Comment: Okay thanks, but does this create conflits if I use UTF-8 everywhere else ?

Comment: I suggest the better solution is to not use those words.  Trying to get tricky with reserved words always leads to trouble when you forget your quoting, not to mention making your code more trouble to read.

Comment: I don't know why you think UTF-8 has anything to do with this.

Comment: Well i'm a complete noob about character encoding, and i've seen in Notepad++ that you can encode in UTF-8 and ANSI, so i've tought using both ANSI and UTF-8 could maybe create problems at some point.

Comment: ANSI in this case means nothing to do with character sets, but just quotation marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL supports the ANSI standard of using double quotes surrounding identifiers such as table and column names.  You have to enable this option since by default MySQL recognizes both single and double quotes as enclosing string literals:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes